# XSD type validation according to one attribute value

Tags: xml, xsd

As I remember, some time ago I had similar piece of XML:

```
<item type="Person" name="Pawel" Surname="Wu" />
<item type="Address" city="Sample town" address="Sample street etc." />
```

and I wantetd to validate it with XSD. However, last time I did it (about 2 years ago I had such a task) it was impossible to specify element type according to attribute value (**type** in this example). So I was forced to redesign XML structure into something like this:

```
<person name=..... />
<address city=..... />
```

and writing XSD was piece of cake.

Today, I have similar issue. As an input I get XML document with generic **item** elements that have **type** attriibute, and latter, depending on this attribute value, another attributes are allowed/required or not. Documents in that shape are still created in system manually, so I would like to have an XSD document that will reduce/eliminate errors (it's easy to forget that element **item** with **type="personalDetails"** must have a particular collection of attributes set).

Is it possible to write a XSD schema to validate such a documents now?

Thanks,Pawel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't validate based on the attributevalue. However, you can use `xsi:type` to specify the type of the element in the XML instance. [Click](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#xsi_type), [click](http://norman.walsh.name/2004/01/29/trainwreck).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with XSD 1.1, currently implemented in Xerces and Saxon (i.e. not yet very widely).

One way to handle validation of a generic vocabulary like this is to transform it prior to validation, ie. convert `<attribute name="size" value="23">` to `<size>23</size>`